# CKEditor Plugin: text fields not editable

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

I am creating a CKEditor plugin, using version 4.2.1. I am trying to follow the [tutorial on a Simple Plugin](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_2). However, the text inputs in my dialog window are not editable / clickable in the dialog, even when I just copy in the entire abbr plugin from the tutorial with no changes.

I can still click the dialog tabs, OK / Cancel buttons, and drag the dialog around. I have added in other elements (like selects) to the dialog in my custom version, and I can interact with those.

When I check the text input elements in Chrome's Dev Tools, I can add text via the Console / jQuery and it appears. I get no failures in the Console.

```
$('#cke_229_textInput').val('help');
```

Will add text to the text input and display it on the screen. But I can't interact with the element via mouse / keyboard / browser. Is there something obvious in the CKEditor configuration that I am missing? Sorry if this is a really stupid question--first time working with CKEditor. I have also searched the CKEditor forums and Google, without finding any related issues.

This happens in both Chrome 30 and FF 24.

My call to create the editor:

```
var me = document.getElementById('resource_editor_raw');
editor = CKEDITOR.replace(me, {
    fullPage: true,
    removePlugins: 'newpage,forms,templates',
    extraPlugins: 'abbr',
    allowedContent: true
});
```

Thanks for any tips or hints!

---

### Update #1

Thinking [this might be related](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-t-edit-fields-of-ckeditor-in-jquery-ui-modal-dialog), I have also tried setting the z-index of the text element to very high, using Chrome's Dev Tools. No luck, it is still not editable / highlightable...

---

### Update #2

This seems to be [this conflict](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9087#comment:14) with jQuery UI. The suggested fix doesn't work for me yet, but will poke around...leaving this up for anyone who might stumble across it.

---

### Final Update

So Brian's tip helped me. Both the Bootbox modal backdrop (what I am using to generate the original dialog) and the CKEditor dialog backdrop have tabindex=-1, so they conflict somehow. Manually turning off the Bootbox backdrop (i.e. setting tabindex='') works with Chrome dev tools, so I think I can hack something together with jQuery or whatnot. Amazing stuff...thanks for the help!! Not sure why I got this working in a jsFiddle...if I recall correctly, I might not have had a backdrop on those dialogs.

Also, for reference, a tabindex of -1 makes things [untabbable](http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/08/tabindex), which makes sense for a backdrop.

Comment: In Bootstrap 5, all I needed to do is add `data-bs-focus="false"` to the html. But this was to get the edit link window working again, not a custom plugin.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The modal html attribute `tabindex='-1'` is what seems to be causing the issues for me.

The `tabindex='-1'` is actually in the bootstrap documentation and is needed for some reason that I am unaware of.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the response, I also put that in there because of the Bootstrap docs. I'll maybe fiddle with this a little more tomorrow, with your insight in mind. I did get the suggested fix working in a jsfiddle, so I know it should work...

Comment: Hm, so this is also my problem. I am using the bootbox library to create the first modal, and its backdrop has a tabindex of -1. But the ckeditor backdrop also has a tabindex of -1, and they appear to conflict. Removing the tabindex on the bootbox backdrop fixes the problem. I can probably hack my way around this now--thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

Use the 100% working script..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Include this file AFTER both jQuery and bootstrap are loaded.
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {
      modal_this = this
      $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
        if (modal_this.$element[0] !== e.target && !modal_this.$element.has(e.target).length 
        && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select') 
        && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_textarea')
        && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')) {
          modal_this.$element.focus()
        }
      })
    };
</script>
```

**Note:** Include this file after both jQuery and bootstrap are loaded.

Comment: Worked like charm! :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if anyone else is having this issue now. I was ripping my hair out trying to create a hack. It was a pretty simple solution after a while of digging and search the web. This fix helped me. Just place it on the same page where you want to place your editor - when loading from jQuery. The issue is conflicting tabindex, so I simply removed that attribute from the modal.

```
<script>
$(function(){ 
       // APPLY THE EDITOR TO THE TEXTAREA
       $(".wysiwyg").ckeditor();

       // FIXING THE MODAL/CKEDITOR ISSUE
       $(".modal").removeAttr("tabindex");
});
</script>
```

Comment: your solution didn't work for me this way. I had to modify `$('.modal').attr('tabindex', '');` then it worked

Answer (score 3):

OMG I have been googling this for hours and finally fond some code that works!!

Stick this in your dialog page that will have a ckeditor in it:

```
orig_allowInteraction = $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction;
$.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction = function(event) {
   if ($(event.target).closest('.cke_dialog').length) {
      return true;
   }
   return orig_allowInteraction.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

I found the fix here:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-t-edit-fields-of-ckeditor-in-jquery-ui-modal-dialog

Answer (score 1):

I am using Semantic UI and fix this problem by create an instance of CKEDITOR after create Modal.

```js
    $('#modal-send').modal('attach events', '.btn-close-modal').modal('show');
    var ckeOptions = {
        entities: false,
        htmlEncodeOutput: false,
        htmlDecodeOutput: true
    }

    CKEDITOR.replace('message', ckeOptions);
    CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'justify';
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue when I updated the CKEditor into 4.14
I found the fix in here - http://jsfiddle.net/kamelkev/HU8Qt/3/
In this case,

```
$.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
        _allowInteraction: function (event) {
            return !!$(event.target).closest(".cke").length || this._super(event);
        }
    });
```

It will return false, so the textbox gets disabled/ unfocused (losing focus)
As a solution, we need to return true or need to modify the class `.cke` in the return statement into `.cke_dialog`

```
 return !!$(event.target).closest(".cke").length || this._super(event);
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried to upload images to server from CK Editor[without CKFinder] and on positive side i am able to do. whenever we are trying to create some dialog, they are creating one `div` on the fly which will hold your dialog box. Better you check the `CSS` property for your text box using chrome and change it. Hope this will help you.