# CKEditor text fields in FileManager dialog contents area not working (alternative text, width, height,...)

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, image-uploading, ckeditor4.x

I am using ckeditor4-react package in my react app. When I want to add image to text, file browser is opening, I select the image or upload the image but I cannot change the size of the image or add alternate text. Because text fields are disabled.

```
let c = { 
filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'http://localhost:3002/admin/photopicker', 
filebrowserUploadUrl: `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${config.cloud_name}/upload`
};

<CKEditor 
config={c} 
ref="editor" 
data={this.props.data} 
onChange={this.props.onEditorChange} 
onFileUploadRequest={this.onFileUploadRequest} 
onFileUploadResponse={this.onFileUploadResponse} 
onDialogShow={this.onDialogShow} />
```

I expect to edit size like in the demo: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/image.html

[Alternative Text, width, height, border, HSpace and VSpace fields are not editable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rydhw.png)

Comment: You want to double-click the image and be able to edit the size?

Comment: I want to change with from Image Properties, Image Info tab Width text box but I can't click the text.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your ckeditor react package has been installed with the

```
config.readOnly
```

property set to true.

Try including this under your CKEditor tag:

```
readOnly={false}
```

or, changing the package configuration.

See: [CKEditor readOnly config property](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_readonly.html) for more info on that.

Comment: This problem is similar with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570661/ckeditor-plugin-text-fields-not-editable  -- however i could not apply the given solution to my code.

Comment: Are you using Bootbox or some other type of library/framework to generate your custom dialog? If that is the case then according to given descriptions, it seems that finding and removing tabindex of -1 from that custom dialog fixes the issue. Have you managed to remove it?

Comment: I am using material-ui version 3.6.2. I modified the dashboard layout. One page is my editor page and I add CKEditor component. I did not use any other library for custom dialog for image import. Dialog is default ckeditor file manager dialog. I think there is a bug in "ckeditor4-react" version "0.1.0". There is no other version for ckeditor 4. Maybe I will try with ckeditor 5.

Comment: I am listening dialog show event. Event fired when a dialog is shown. It returns an evt parameter that includes This editor instance and The opened dialog instance.
I try to remove tab index with this => evt.data.parts.dialog.$.tabIndex = undefined
and evt.data.parts.contents.$.tabIndex = undefined commands but it did not effect