# ckeditor's popup input fields dont work when used with bootstrap 5 modal (ckeditor 4)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ckeditor, bootstrap-5

I have come across an error while using ckeditor in bootstrap 5 modal and it looks like it's a very known error and many have given solution for it for different bootstrap versions but i am not able to figure out one for bootstrap 5, please have a look.

Here is the problem with solution:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31679096

Other similar problems:-

[CKEditor Plugin: text fields not editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570661/ckeditor-plugin-text-fields-not-editable)

[Bootstrap with CKEditor equals problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420300/bootstrap-with-ckeditor-equals-problems/18554395#18554395)

Mainly what would be the alternative of below line for bootstrap 5. $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus

If I search for it in bootstrap 4 js file I'm able to find fn.modal.Constructor in there but not in bootstrap 5. Please if someone can recreate the verified solution in the above link according to bootstrap 5 it would be very appreciated. Thank you for your time.

[image describing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X04EL.png)

Also few notes:-

1. All the other input types like checkboxes and dropdown works but not just text field.
2. I have also tried removing tabindex="-1" from bootstrap modal code but the problem remains.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. Solutions don't go in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for this. Saved me a lot of head scratching. As of Bootstrap 5.3, this requires a small tweak:

```
bootstrap.Modal.prototype._initializeFocusTrap = function () { return { activate: function () { }, deactivate: function () { } } };
```

Comment: This answer is very useful. it saved my time. Thanks a lot dear

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you figured out the answer to this yet, but I've had this same issue with a sweetalert2 modal. I scoured bootstrap's source code and found that you can remove the focus with this:

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._initializeFocusTrap = function () { return { activate: function () { }, deactivate: function () { } } };
```

Works as of Bootstrap 5.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap does not support [nesting modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) disabling enforce focus will allow other modals to get focused: `<Modal enforceFocus={false}>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you've already solved it, but so others who encounter the error have it, the solution for me, with Bootstrap 5.3 and CKEditor 4, was to add
data-bs-focus="false"
to the modal's HTML.

By deactivating the modal's automatic focus, it ensures that the elements within the modal are ready to be initialized correctly when the shown.bs.modal event is triggered